# SQL - get last row in date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing:
Balance, Client_ID, Date

This table has ~25 Million rows - Most days, a service executes and creates a new row for each client, with today's date, and balance of the client.

Inside a date range, lets say 01/01/2016 to 12/05/2016, I need to get the first and last row.

*the service does not run every day, so doing Date = 12/05/2016 will not work. If today's balance is equal to yesterday's balance, there is no row inserted (saves me about 90% of the data, which if I calculate correctly, should be 300 Million rows)

To do such, I run these two queries:
Get the first date: `6.9433851242065 seconds`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM daily
            WHERE TIME >= '01/01/2016' AND TIME < '13/05/2016') dates
GROUP BY Client_ID
```

Get the last date: `32.034277915955 seconds`

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM daily
            WHERE TIME >= '01/01/2016' AND TIME < '13/05/2016'
            ORDER BY Date DESC) dates
GROUP BY Client_ID
```

The first query has no order, because rows are inserted always in the right order, by the service mentioned above - and such is much faster. (7/32)

How can I make both queries faster, or at least the second one?

Query description:

- Get the row where the date is the first date after 01/01/2016
- Get the row where the date is the last date before 13/05/2016

**EDIT: The checked answer gives me the following:**

ASC and DESC are mine, 'combined' is the suggested answer

---

- dates_ASC: 33.300458192825
- dates_DESC: 8.9232740402222
- dates_combined: 8.4357199668884

---

- dates_ASC: 5.4825110435486
- dates_DESC: 10.173403978348
- dates_combined: 2.7024359703064

---

- dates_ASC: 15.090759038925
- dates_DESC: 29.375104904175
- dates_combined: 3.2885720729828

Comment: First, are you sure you need the nested SELECT? And are you sure you need all the returned fields? Also, I would try `SELECT TOP 1 *`.

Comment: Why not use `ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Oh, MySQL, yes. LIMIT 1 rather than SELECT TOP 1.

Comment: Just noticed its a list, so probably `GROUP BY()` together with `MAX()` and `MIN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick each client's min and max time in a derived table. Join with that table:

```
select *
from daily d1
  join (select Client_ID, max(TIME) as maxtime, min(TIME) as mintime
        from daily
        WHERE TIME >= '01/01/2016' AND TIME < '13/05/2016'
        group by Client_ID) d2
 on d1.Client_ID = d2.Client_ID and d1.TIME in (d2.mintime, d2.maxtime)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Results are in the edited post - check em out

Answer (score 0):

Try first query as:

```
SELECT * FROM daily WHERE TIME >= '01/01/2016' AND TIME < '13/05/2016' ORDER BY TIME ASC LIMIT 1
```

The second query as:

```
SELECT * FROM daily WHERE TIME >= '01/01/2016' AND TIME < '13/05/2016' ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1
```